# Wrong OpenGL Texture Format Type for CL/GL-Interop?

Tags: opengl, opencl, texture2d, libavcodec

I'm trying the OpenCL-OpenGL interop for textures on my Geforce 330M with CUDA Toolkit 4.0.

I want to capture a frame, use that data as an input image (`Image2D`) to a OpenCL Kernel. The Kernel should manipulate the data and write it to an `Image2DGL`, which is an image object with an attached OpenGL texture. Basically it looks like that:

```
 _______________      RGB        _______________
|               |    uint8*     |               |   CL_RGBA / CL_UNORM_INT8
|   Grabber     | ------------> |   Image2D     | -------------------------.
|   avcodec     |               |   [input]     |                          |
|_______________|               |_______________|                          |
                                                                           |    
                                                                           V
 _______________                 _______________                       _______________
|               |               |               |                     |               |
|   Texture     | ------------> |   Image2DGL   | <-----------------> |    Kernel     |
|_______________|               |   [output]    |                     |_______________|
                                |_______________|
Internal
Format: GL_RGBA
Format: GL_RGBA
Type: ?
```

I'm initializing the texture like that:

```
GLuint tex = 0;

void initTexture( int width, int height )
{
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, tex);
// now here is where I need assistance: The type parameter of the Texture (GL_FLOAT)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL );
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I can have a type of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as well.

---

Then I create the shared image (`Image2DGL`):

```
texMems.push_back(Image2DGL(clw->context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, tex, &err));
```

Then I create the source image (input image):

```
ImageFormat format;
format.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNORM_INT8;
format.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
srcImgBuffer = Image2D(clw->context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, format, width, height, 0, NULL, &err);
```

In every render loop I'm writing the data into the `srcImgBuffer`:

```
// write the frame to the image buffer
clw->queue.enqueueWriteImage(srcImgBuffer, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, (void*)data, NULL, NULL);
```

Also I'm setting the arguments for the kernel:

```
tex_kernel.setArg(0, texMems[0]);
tex_kernel.setArg(1, srcImgBuffer);
tex_kernel.setArg(2, width);
tex_kernel.setArg(3, height);
```

Before and after I do acquire and release the GL objects. The testing kernel looks like that:

```
__kernel void init_texture_kernel(__write_only image2d_t out, __read_only image2d_t in, int w, int h)
{
    const sampler_t smp = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

    int2 coords = { get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1) };
    float4 pixel = read_imagef(in, smp, coords);
    float4 test = { (float)coords.x/(float)w , 0, 0, 1};
    write_imagef( out, coords, pixel );
}
```

The `image_channel_data_type` can be read as float in the kernel and is interpreted as normalized value. The output image looks not right, I've got a sliced picture (linewise), obviously because of the wrong data interpretation. As I mentioned I assume the error is within the initialization of the texture's type. I tried GL_FLOAT (as I'm writing as float to the image in the kernel).

[image: Results: Image as PPM dump from the decoder (left), Texture output scattered (right)]

The left one is a `PPM` out of the decoder, the right one is what I'm getting back on my output texture.

If someone actually read up to here: Do you have suggestions regarding the texture's type to resolve the issue?

---

**EDIT:** If I bind the captured frames to the texture directly, the video plays ok. So it must be related to the CL-GL interface somehow.

---

Comment: Did Image2DGL return an error? And what happens if you use a regular 2D texture instead of a rectangle texture?

Comment: No, no error from Image2DGL. I tried 2D before, normalized the texture coords and set the Mag/Min filter as well as the wrap, but have no output at all then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came up with the solution, not seeing the obvious. I had an RGB video. I captured the frames in RGB therefore. This can be displayed on a texture just fine. HOWEVER, if one grabs a `float4` from the buffer at once (as seen in the kernel code) where only three channels are present, this is going to mess it up, of course. Argh.

I also could have assumed my mistake by watching the line count: I got 384 out of 512 lines  requested lines, which well comes up to a ratio of `.75`.

I simply demanded my grabber (using libavcodec) to grab RGBA and it would pad it for me to have a four-channel picture.

I will flag this question to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if your last argument to glTexture2D is NULL, then format and type arguments can any valid OpenGL format/type - but they are not used and doesn't influence anything. If you want to have floating point texture, then you must specify it by passing correct internal_format argument:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

Comment: I can understand what you mean, however my source data is of type uint8 and I'm looking for a correspondig type for the texture. I can't really see any 8bit data type.

Comment: If I don't initialize the texture once like that in the beginning, I cannot see any output, so I take it that I need it. I can however have `GL_RGBA8` or `GL_RGBA32F`, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I don't understand it.

Comment: 7th and 8th argument for glTexImage2D specifies in what format and type data is passed in last argument. If you don't pass any data to glTexImage2D then values in these two arguments doesn't influence nothing.

Comment: So if I specify `GL_RGB` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, then that comes close to what i am actually providing. The thing is the texture `tex` is bound indirectly through an `Image2DGL`, I never pass the data directly into the texture by for example `glTexImage2D`.

Comment: And although the combination of the above is supposed to create a valid Image2DGL memory object, it is failing to do so.